# schtasks - Why doesn't this work?

Tags: windows, command-line, scheduled-tasks, task-scheduler, syntax

I type this into cmd or in a batch script:

```
schtasks /change /RP user_password /TN "existing_task" /ST H:M
```

If /ST H:M has two digits in the hour it says ERROR: The parameter is incorrect.

If /ST H:M has on digit in the hour it says ERROR: Invalid starttime value.

This should work but for some reason doesn't.

How would I go about making this work so it sets the start time of an existing task?

Comment: What is the exact command you are using? Hint: you need to specify both hours **and** minutes

Comment: I do specify both minutes and hours can be any where from 5:30 to 23:01 and I still get the error.

Comment: Strange. It works for me.

Comment: The task is in a separate folder. Would that make a difference?i.e. /TN "folder\task_name"

Comment: The name of the task `/tn` has nothing to do with folders. You would use a folder with `/tr`

Comment: If I use a folder name as part of the task name there is an error "ERROR: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect."

Comment: Again, What is the **exact** command you are using?

Comment: When I ommit the folder in /TN it says the task doesn't exist. The exact command is what iv'e said with user_password being my pc's account password and /ST being a valid 24-hr time in the format HH:MM generated by a program.

Comment: Well I cannot **create** a task with the taskname `/tn "c:\windows\demo"`

Comment: Sorry, I probably won't clear when I say folder I meant folder in task scheduler library. i.e "Morning Tasks\Start Toaster"

Comment: `SCHTASKS /change /tn "morning tasks\start toaster" /tr "C:\Windows\notepad.exe" /st 01:01` work for me. I am prompted for a password ...

Comment: When I use that command after creating that task it says: The parameter is incorrect. Any ideas?

Comment: No. It all seems to work as expected for me.

Comment: I have figured it out it all works now. It was erroring out because the first char of my tasks name was an integer

Comment: Please read [Can I answer my own question?](http://superuser.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 0):

Creating an answer for this question so that others might not have to read all the comments

1. Make sure StartTime is the format "HH:MM", i.e. `9:00` will output `ERROR: Invalid starttime value`, `09:00` should work
2. Make sure your TaskName does not start with an integer